# Haskell type synonym

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to understand what the following type synonym from Yesod is doing.

`type HtmlUrlI18n msg url = Translate msg -> Render url -> Html`

I could not find an example in learn you some haskell or the haskell wikibook of a type synonym with `->` present.  Any links or explanations are much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: It's just a synonym for a function type.

Comment: Everywhere you see `HtmlUrlI18n msg url`, replace that with `Translate msg -> Render url -> Html`.

Comment: To add to what the cat said: It's done because the right hand type signature is a bit unwieldy, and perhaps hard to remember. Suppose you have a function that takes a `Translate msg -> Render url -> Html` as one of many arguments. That quickly gets unreadable and perhaps unclear, whereas having it take a `HtmlUrlI18n msg url` is much better.

Comment: Types representing functions took me a while to grasp. This is the meat and potatoes of Haskell. You're good now!

Comment: Syntax for the function type is no different from any other type. Data constructor `->` is different from, for example, `Either` only by its infix position. Type `Translate msg -> Render url -> Html` is equivalent to `(->) (Translate msg) ((->) (Render url) Html)`. By the way, you can define your own infix types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its just a synonym for a (long to write down) function type. For example, the following should be valid Haskell

```
--Example of a function type synonym
type StrFn = String -> String

foo :: StrFn
foo s = s ++ "!"

--Example of a function type synonym with type parameters
type Fn a = a -> a

bar :: Fn String
bar s = s ++ "?"
```

Comment: Thanks so much to everyone for your answers.  Very helpful.

Comment: @David: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted, so the question leaves the unanswered tab. You can also write an answer of your own if you want.